# Simplest way to toggle functionality in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Anyways I’m trying to make a lightbulb.  It’s just a circle, I have an `onclick` event on a button, and the event function toggled a class, changing the color.  But I want the text in the button to toggle as well when that class is activated.

I finally made it work as I was writing this question.  But it still isn’t working how I want it. I only want to have one if statement.

I only want to solve it this specific way, by checking if a class is activated, and if yes, then change the text content of the button, if not, then leave it how it is.

```js
let bulb = document.getElementById("light");
let lightSwitch = document.getElementById("switch");

function activity(event) {
  bulb.classList.toggle("lightOn");

  if (bulb.classList.contains("lightOn")) {
    lightSwitch.textContent = "OFF";
  } else if (bulb.classList.contains("lightOff")) {

    lightSwitch.textContent = "ON";
  }

}
```

```css
.lightOn {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="light" class="lightOff"></div>
<button id="switch" onclick="activity()">ON</button>
```

How can I write it with only one if statement, Also, is there a way easier than this?  Just vanilla not jQuery.

Comment: My bad, I was eating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

```js
...

function activity(event) {
   bulb.classList.toggle("lightOn");
   lightSwitch.textContent = bulb.classList.contains("lightOn") ? "OFF" : "ON";
}

...
```

Comment: I did think about using a ternary operator but I didn’t know how to get it working.  

Can you explain to me what’s going on, I understand it’s basically contusion, action if true, then action if false.  But I don’t really get what’s on the left of .contains ……

Comment: *what’s on the left of `.contains`*. well, `bulb` is a dom element or dom node. dom element or dom node has many properties like style, scrollHeight, scrollWeight, etc. one of them is classList. classList is a [DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) also has its own properties and methods like length, add, remove, etc. you'll see if you `console.log(bulb.classList)`. [more on that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: the one we're using is `contains` which returns a boolean value `true` if the underlying list contains the given token, otherwise `false`. in our case, the list is `classList` and the token is `"lightOn"`. [more on that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains).

Comment: a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#:~:text=The%20conditional%20(ternary)%20operator%20is,if%20the%20condition%20is%20falsy.) is basically a shorthand `if...else` statement. in our case `bulb.classList.contains("lightOn") ? "OFF" : "ON"` is basically like `if(bulb.classList.contains("lightOn")) lightSwitch.textContent = "OFF" else lightSwitch.textContent = "ON"`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be simplified by extracting the bulb-specific default styles into a `light` class, then only toggle a new `lightOn` class. The default styles describe what to show if the bulb is off, but you can override those styles with [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/important) in the `lightOn` class. Just like this:

```js
let bulb = document.getElementById("light");
let lightSwitch = document.getElementById("switch");

lightSwitch.addEventListener('click', function() {
  bulb.classList.toggle('lightOn');
  lightSwitch.textContent = bulb.classList.contains("lightOn") ? "OFF" : "ON";
});
```

```css
.light {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: gray;
}

.lightOn {
  background: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="light" class="light"></div>
<button id="switch">ON</button>
```

You can also shorten your if-statement into a [ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), which is a better choice for this situation because only one value changes.